# Query return error (Room Dao) while retrieving boolean data

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to fetch a set of data from room dao. And the query is

```
 @Query("select * from inventory_tags_list where isDiscover = :true")
public List<InventoryTags> getNewTags();
```

and I get this error:

> Error:(26, 32) error: Each bind variable in the query must have a matching method parameter. Cannot find method parameters for :true.

`isDiscover` is a `boolean` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping in Room of True to 1 and False to 0. Try this

```
 @Query("select * from inventory_tags_list where isDiscover = 1")
 public List<InventoryTags> getNewTags();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need bind variables. This one must work.

```
@Query("select * from inventory_tags_list where isDiscover = 1")
public List<InventoryTags> getNewTags();
```